# border-radius style property not rounding the edges in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

I want the edges of the div c-thumbnail__container to be rounded, but it is not working at all. Is there a way to do this?

```
const Thumbnail = () => {
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState((false));
    return (
        <>
            <div className='c-thumbnail__container' onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}>
                <img src={example} alt="Thumbnail" />
                <Bookmark onClick={onClickBook}/>
                {isShown && (
                    <BtnPlay />
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
.c-thumbnail__container{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    
    min-width: 164px;
    min-height: 110px;
}

.c-thumbnail__container:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: brightness(.7);
}
```

Comment: have you tried with e.g. `border-radius: 25px;`?

Comment: You haven't added border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

To add a border radius, you have to add the `border-radius` property to the elements CSS. It looks like you have forgotten to do that.

This CSS will fix your problem:

```
.c-thumbnail__container{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    
    min-width: 164px;
    min-height: 110px;

    // added:
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.c-thumbnail__container:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: brightness(.7);
}
```

Learn more about `border-radius` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: I just delete because it's not working. I didn't forget.